# How can I make a date time picker always contain the last day of the month while showing month and year only?

Tags: c#, exception, event-handling, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker which I have set to only show the month and year as follows:

```
myDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
myDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "MMMM yyyy";
myDateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

However, I want the value of the date to always be the last day of the selected month, so I set the DateTime in the ValueChanged event using:

```
DateTime selectedDate = myDateTimePicker.Value;
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(
    selectedDate.Year,
    selectedDate.Month,
    DateTime.DaysInMonth(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month));
myDateTimePicker.Value = lastDayOfMonth;
```

The problem is, if I have a month like March selected, and I change the month to February using the up/down controls, I get the following error before I can handle the ValueChanged event:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
```

This is understandable because the date was 31 March and it is being changed to 31 February which is an invalid date. However, I want to change it to 28 February (or 29 February).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a bug in DateTimePicker.  Workaround is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/69b10b5b-a034-426e-a045-2bed8a1637a3

Comment: You should put that as an answer, @HansPassant :)

Comment: I already answered it, I'm not picky about where :)

Comment: @HansPassant, true - but it's not about karma whoring :)  I'll be easier to find the answer for future searches if it's in the right place :)

Comment: Thanks @Hans. However, I'm having this problem not just with leap years. It's when changing from any month that has a greater number of days to any month that has fewer. The workaround looks promising but complex. I had hoped there would be a more elegant way to achieve this...

Comment: @WarrenBlumenow, perhaps you can catch the exception and silently set the last day appropriately.  Not sure if this is elegant or whether it would work in the context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Workaround and elegant are also two words rarely seen in one sentence.  I thought the fix I came up with was pretty elegant, tickles the fancy of a Win32 hacker anyway.  But yes, rarely appreciated on a site like SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very strange, I tried to reproduce your problem, and when I switch from March to February, my control just doesn't display anything... 
Maybe we have different framework versions, who handle the same error differently.

Anyway, one solution would be to set the datetime picker to the first of each month, and when you need the value, you can just use your code as it currently is:

```
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(
    selectedDate.Year, 
    selectedDate.Month, 
    DateTime.DaysInMonth(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month));
```

Since you never use the day value of your dattime picker, you can just set it to 1, which will always give an existing date.

This solution leaves me with a bad feeling somehow, since you are using a date that differs from the date you get from your control -  always a possible source of errors, IMO. Remember to put comments into your code, explaining why you are doing it this way ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Treb. That's an interesting approach. I agree that it's a possible source of bugs though, so to be used very carefully. If nobody suggests anything better, I will probably have to do this :-(

Comment: I tried to override `PreProcessMessage` to capture the message before the internal DateTime of the control was accessed, but no such luck. btw, during testing I noticed that the `ValueChanged` event was always fired twice: First by the change initiated through the form, and second by calling `dateTimePicker1.Value = lastDayOfMonth;`...

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I don't find it nice - it's certainly simple which is usually a good thing. But as stated in my answer, I am worried about bugs creeping in because of it.

Comment: @Treb, sometimes the conditions that we are forced to work with redefines what "nice" actually is.  In this case, it solves the problem and there may well be bugs further down the line.  At the end of the day, we do what we can :)

Comment: @Treb and Moo-Juice: Thanks both for your help with this. If it's a choice between bugs in the DateTimePicker implementation that I have no control over and bugs in my code which I do have control over, then I will choose the latter :-) As Moo-Juice said, we do what we can...

Comment: There is no room for bad feelings here. This solution is correct as it is. When I save a date to a database I set hours, minutes etc. to 0 so I can compare dates with `=` later. If the user doesn't care about the day and wants month and year only the next best (simplest) thing must be taken for undefined values. And in that case it is day 1. I stumbled over this error just today because it's the 30th. Lucky me I'm developing right now so I don't have to debug it later.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use the 1st of the month like Treb Selected, but extend DateTimePicker so that when you did this:

`MyDateTimePicker.Value`

it would do something like this:

```
get{
return value.addMonths(1).addDays(-1)
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion to extend DateTimePicker to hide the ugly workaround